# KQL / Azure Resource Graph Explorer: combine values from multiple records

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to fetch all public ips and fqdns configured for a set of load balancers in azure resource graph explorer. I am getting all the data I need with the following query:

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers'
| where subscriptionId =~ '11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555'
| where resourceGroup =~ 'resource-group-name'
| mv-expand ipConfig=properties.frontendIPConfigurations
| project name, publicIpId = tostring(ipConfig.properties.publicIPAddress.id)
| join kind=leftouter (
    Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses'
    | project publicIpId = id, publicIpAddress = tostring(properties.ipAddress), fqdn = tostring(properties.dnsSettings.fqdn)
)
on publicIpId
| summarize by name, publicIpAddress, fqdn
```

But the result is in the form of:

```
name              publicIpAddress       fqdn
outbound-lb       x.y.z.1               a domain
frontend-lb       x.y.z.2               another domain
frontend-lb       x.y.z.3               third domain
services-lb       x.y.z.4               fourth domain
```

and what I need is:

```
name              publicIpAddress       fqdn
outbound-lb       x.y.z.1               a domain
frontend-lb       x.y.z.2, x.y.z.3      another domain, third domain
services-lb       x.y.z.4               fourth domain
```

I have been looking at the `summarize make_list()` function but was not successful in getting the result I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try replacing this:

```
| summarize by name, publicIpAddress, fqdn
```

with this:

```
| summarize publicIpAddress = strcat_array(make_set(publicIpAddress), ", "), 
            fqdn = strcat_array(make_set(fqdn), ", ")
         by name
```

Comment: Thanks soo much for your quick answer! I am new to KQL and the Azure Resource Explorer and spent quite some time on this without making any progress! Now it works!